# Created a new iframe app but can not find it

Tags: facebook, iframe

I have succesfully created a business page and iframe app and had little issues. However I am trying to do the same for another business. I have created the app as before but can not add the app.

Last time to add the app I went to my business page then in the facebook search box I typed the name of my app. I am trying to do the same this time but my app is not appearing.

I created the app a few days ago. What am I missing?

Comment: Is it not at https://developers.facebook.com/apps ?

Answer (score 2):

This is something I recently noticed too.

You have to manually go to add the app... use this URL and replace [APP ID] with your app ID

http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=[APP-ID]&pages=1